# Why LOOP is terminating right away?

Tags: javascript

I am seraching a match in a string by using search function, say like below JS......say, 1st result is found,well.......2nd is found, well....3rd id not found, then the control/cursor is coming out of the loop, i mean, right away the loop is terminating, i thought the ELSE condition is gonnna trigger and continues the iteration until the end of the length...but in the middle its terminating! Pls. suggest me either fix or provide a new JS, Thank you

```
// OriginalFields is a string, its fillled with fields list with space seperator
myArrayGrey = greyFields.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < myArrayGrey.length; i++) {
    var returnValue = OriginalFields.search(myArrayGrey[i]);
    if (returnValue != -1) {
        //grey the field 
        // and
        // make access = "readOnly";
    };
    else {;
        // do nothing
        // just for my testing am doing app.alert (not found)
    };
};​
```

Comment: Hey @JuanMendes, see that [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13038343/edit) link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable answer, since your OP does not include much details, is because `myArrayGrey = greyFields.split(" ");` returns an empty array.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Sorry for poor OP.Actually, the resaon is the above said by 2 experts

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error (actually, two). Remove the semicolons after the closing bracket for the `if`, and after the opening bracket for the `else`. And you can also get rid of the other semicolons after the `else` and `for` closing brackets (although they won't cause syntax errors – your problem was separating `if` and `else`):

```
// OriginalFields is a string, its fillled with fields list with space seperator
myArrayGrey = greyFields.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < myArrayGrey.length; i++) {
    var returnValue = OriginalFields.search(myArrayGrey[i]);
    if (returnValue != -1) {
        //grey the field 
        // and
        // make access = "readOnly";
    } else {
        // do nothing
        // just for my testing am doing app.alert (not found)
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if` and `for` blocks don't need the semicolons either.